# Heatmap with categorical variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am trying to create a heatmap with long form data to assess the correlation between membership of individual groups on specific outcome measure scores. I have converted the data to long format as shown. Some individuals may be members of more than 1 group.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
               Group1= c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0),
               Group2 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
               Measurement = c("Pain", "Pain", "Fatigue", "Stiffness", "Fatigue"),
               Score = c(2, 3, 3, 2, 3))

df1
ID Group1 Group2 Measurement Score
1  1      1      1        Pain     2
2  2      1      0        Pain     3
3  3      0      1     Fatigue     3
4  4      1      0   Stiffness     2
5  5      0      0     Fatigue     3
```

I am sure this is a very basic question so my apologies. I would like to create a heatmap-like plot in ggplot with a colour scale representing the scores and x axis= Group memberships, y-axis = Measurements

Running the code below yields the following:

```
fig1 <- ggplot(df1,  aes(x =  c("Group1", "Group2"),
                     y = "Measurement", 
                     fill = "Score")) + geom_tile()
```

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (5): x

Is there a way of having a list of categorical variables on the y and x axes as described?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code:

1. You use quotes `"` around column names which is the reason why you get the error message.
2. You can't map two columns on one aesthetic, i.e. even when removing the quotes `c(Group1, Group2)` will not work. Instead combine both variables into one for which I use `dplyr::case_when`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(Group = dplyr::case_when(
    Group1 == 1 & Group2 == 1 ~ "Group 1 & 2",
    Group1 == 1 ~ "Group 1",
    Group2 == 1 ~ "Group 2",
    TRUE ~ "None"
  ))

ggplot(df1, aes(
  x = Group,
  y = Measurement,
  fill = Score
)) +
  geom_tile()
```

[image]